# Replacing a character with span class style: IE different than Mozilla

Tags: internet-explorer, replace, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .spades { color: blue; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 120%; font-weight:bold }
      .hearts { color: red; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 120%; font-weight:bold }
      .diams { color: #FF6600; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 120%; font-weight:bold }
      .clubs { color: #009D00; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 120%}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="bid_done('2C','TESTSTRING')">
    <table id="bidsdone" border="1">
      <caption><b>Bids done:</b></caption>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
    TEST3
    <div>
      <p id="clu"><span class="clubs">&clubs;</span></p>
      <p id="dia"><span class="diams">&diams;</span></p>
      <p id="hea"><span class="hearts">&hearts;</span></p>
      <p id="spa"><span class="spades">&spades;</span></p>
    </div>

  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function add_bid_done() {
        var table=document.getElementById("bidsdone");
        var row=table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
      }

      function bid_done(x,bc) {
        add_bid_done();
        var bid_abbr = x;
        var bidsdoneRows=1;
        var bidsdoneCell=0;
        var rows=document.getElementById("bidsdone").rows;
        var rowCells=rows[bidsdoneRows].cells;
        x=x.replace(/C/g,document.getElementById("clu").innerHTML);
        x=x.replace(/D/g,document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML);
        x=x.replace(/H/g,document.getElementById("hea").innerHTML);
        x=x.replace(/S/g,document.getElementById("spa").innerHTML);
        x=x.replace(/N/g,"NT");
        rowCells[bidsdoneCell].innerHTML=x;
        rowCells[bidsdoneCell].title=bc;
        rowCells[bidsdoneCell].abbr=bid_abbr;
        rowCells[bidsdoneCell].setAttribute('onclick', 'alert(title)');
      }
  </script>
</html>
```

Above code works in Firefox 10.0.4 but not in IE7. (This is only part of the code to show the issue that I have.)
I have two issues in IE7:

1. It displays "2<♠PANT class=clubs>♣♠PANT>" iso the Green Clubs character.
2. the onclick seems not to work.

Thanks,
Koen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are doing one replace after the other, the HTML code from one replace will be affected by the other replaces. As the `innerHTML` returns different values in different browsers, the result differs.

Some browsers return the HTML tags in uppercase, so when the `C` character in `'2C'` is replaced by a SPAN tag in uppercase, the other replaces will replace the `S` and `N` in the string.

Do all the replaces at once, then one replace won't affect another:

```
x = x.replace(/[CDHSN]/g, function(m){
  switch (m) {
    case 'C': return document.getElementById("clu").innerHTML;
    case 'D': return document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML;
    case 'H': return document.getElementById("hea").innerHTML;
    case 'S': return document.getElementById("spa").innerHTML;
  }
  return "NT";
});
```

You don't have any `title` variable, so `alert(title)` will fail. I suppose that you want to show the title of the element:

```
rowCells[bidsdoneCell].onclick = function () { alert(this.title); };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Rem: There are some ')' too much in your example.
Is it correct that this does not work in a textarea?

Comment: I found:
"The setAttribute() method is supported in all major browsers.
Internet Explorer 8 and earlier does not support this method."

Comment: @user1798023: Thanks, corrected the example. There is no reason it shouldn't work with a textarea. You can set the `onclick` property instead of using `setAttribute`. See edit above.

Comment: Thanks! Alert now works also in IE7.
But span is not working in textarea or in alert box. I'll verify if I better use something else than a textarea (It is only for output and should display a line for each button clicked by the user)